# Find string then look behind to find another with regex

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I basically have a txt file listing all job definitions.  I'd like to figure out which of these jobs use global variables which are always in the format of (v(someText).  Is it possible using regex to match the variable, then match the preceding jobname?  In this example I was hoping to match vaiable1 and variable2 with jobnameB (ideally in two matches with capture groups)

```
/* ----------------- jobnameA ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameA   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 1


/* ----------------- jobnameB ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameB   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: tu,we,th,fr,sa
condition: s(job1) & s(job2) & (v(variable1) = "Y" | s(job1)) & (v(variable2) = "Y" 
alarm_if_fail: 1
job_load: 1
priority: 10


/* ----------------- jobnameC ----------------- */ 
...
```

I can match all variables using:

```
\(v\((.*?)\)
```

And all jobs with something like:

```
insert_job: (\S*?)\s
```

But I'd like to conditionally match the jobname on the presence of the variable.
Or is regex not the best way to achieve this?

Comment: .NET (using VS 2013, coding in VB)

Comment: ideally a matching pair of variable and jobname...presence of the variable should drive the search...or I was hoping to loop through the matches with each one having a group for the variable and one for the jobname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use an expensive variable length lookbehind.
No fancy tables, charts, graphs or demo links here.
Just the better solution ...

Use the *Power* of C# and get something done.
CaptureCollections are your friend.

```
 (?ms)
 ^  [ \t]*  /\* [\s-]* 
 ( \w* )                       # (1)
 [\s-]* \*/
 (?:
      (?:
           (?!
                ^  [ \t]*  /\* [\s-]* 
                \w* 
                [\s-]* \*/
           )
           . 
      )*?
      \(v\( [ \t]* 
      ( \w+ )                       # (2)
      [ \t]* \)

 )+
```

C# sample, see it here =>  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mhmjh6

```
string sAllJobs = @"
/* ----------------- jobnameA ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameA   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 0
alarm_if_fail: 1


/* ----------------- jobnameB ----------------- */ 

insert_job: jobnameB   job_type: CMD 
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: tu,we,th,fr,sa
condition: s(job1) & s(job2) & (v(variable1) = ""Y"" | s(job1)) & (v(variable2) = ""Y"" 
alarm_if_fail: 1
job_load: 1
priority: 10


/* ----------------- jobnameC ----------------- */ 
...
";

Regex RxJobs = new Regex(@"(?ms)^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*(\w*)[\s-]*\*/(?:(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*\w*[\s-]*\*/).)*?\(v\([ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*\))+");
Match matchJobs = RxJobs.Match(sAllJobs);
while (matchJobs.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection ccJobVar = matchJobs.Groups[2].Captures;
    Console.WriteLine("Job Name: {0}", matchJobs.Groups[1].Value );
    for (int i=0; i<ccJobVar.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("  var{0} = {1}", i+1, ccJobVar[i].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    matchJobs = matchJobs.NextMatch();
}
```

Output

```
Job Name: jobnameB
  var1 = variable1
  var2 = variable2
```

**VB.net Sample**
Translated from the C# sample.

*Update note* - This is a working VB.net version,
you can see it here =>  https://dotnetfiddle.net/2yE1ux

In my original translation, I did not realize VB doesn't access elements
using the square bracket notation `[]`.
Evidently, their array access is with the parenthesis notation `()`.
Other than that, it's exactly the same as C# above.

One note, I could not get the sample to work within a *CDATA* element.
I used the Import Core, Xml, and Linq without success on Dotnetfiddle.
I converted the sample the old fashion multi-line VB string way.

VB sample

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()

        Dim sAllJobs As String = " /* ----------------- jobnameA ----------------- */" & Environment.NewLine & _
        " " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " insert_job: jobnameA   job_type: CMD " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " date_conditions: 0 " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " alarm_if_fail: 1 " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " /* ----------------- jobnameB ----------------- */ " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " insert_job: jobnameB   job_type: CMD " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " date_conditions: 1 " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " days_of_week: tu,we,th,fr,sa " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " condition: s(job1) & s(job2) & (v(variable1) = ""Y"" | s(job1)) & (v(variable2) = ""Y""  & Environment.NewLine " & _
        " alarm_if_fail: 1 " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " job_load: 1 " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " priority: 10 " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " /* ----------------- jobnameC ----------------- */ " & Environment.NewLine & _
        " ... "

        Dim RxJobs As New Regex("(?ms)^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*(\w*)[\s-]*\*/(?:(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*\w*[\s-]*\*/).)*?\(v\([ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*\))+")
        Dim matchJobs As Match = RxJobs.Match(sAllJobs)

        Do While matchJobs.Success
            Dim ccJobVar As CaptureCollection = matchJobs.Groups(2).Captures
            Console.WriteLine("Job Name: {0}", matchJobs.Groups(1).Value )
            For ctr As Integer = 0 To ccJobVar.Count - 1
                Console.WriteLine("  var{0} = {1}", ctr+1, ccJobVar(ctr).Value)
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("")
            matchJobs = matchJobs.NextMatch()
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output

```
Job Name: jobnameB
  var1 = variable1
  var2 = variable2
```

Comment: I'd like to check this out but is it doable in VB.net?  I've already got the code but I'm not getting any matches on the string.

Comment: @EphronClarke - Not sure what you mean by if it's doable. The _Dot.Net_ engine covers all of it's supported languages. So, yes I guess it's doable. Sounds like you've never used regular expressions in VB.net. I never use vb.net, but I posted an untested translated version for you. You might want to google to a MS page that define this all in C# / VB.net. There is a ton of them out there.

Comment: thanks for your help, but the condescension isnt necessary.  I asked if it was doable since you were stressing C# despite me saying it was in VB. I also asked since (yes I was able to translate all by my wittle self) your code didnt work when I put it in VB...what I didnt have was the <![CDATA[  so I will try it with that

Comment: @EphronClarke - Nobody is here to service your needs or provide on-demand code for you or anybody else. I post code as a favor using my valuable time, and it's not posted for you personally, it's for the readers. We try to keep it polite at SO. If you think I'm being condescending, you might look at this way, VB.net was never in your original post, and it's twice now you've said `not getting any matches` with my regex, when clear as day is a running sample right before your eyes. It doesn't matter to me if you like another answer better than mine, but don't color mine as not working.

Comment: It's funny how some people like to help with one hand while hitting with the other.  I try to remain grateful when others try to help which is why I will always thank for input, but you took it off the rails...does 'Sounds like you've never used regular expressions in VB.net' seem like yur trying to be polite?  It was absolutely unnecessary and off-base.  Fact is, I tried your suggestion, didn't work.  Liked someone else's answer as it solved my problem in the language I was using.  Sorry your feelings got hurt.

Comment: @EphronClarke - I'm thick skinned and don't have feelings. I hacked it out on Dotnetfiddle, posted the results and links to samples. The VB issue is that the groups elements are accessed with paren's `()` whereas in C# it's with square brackets `[]` otherwise, the translation is identical. That was the only change to make the VB sample work.

Comment: as I said earlier, the code conversion wasnt the issue, it was the fact that you were stressing C# that gave me pause... I had to change the expression a bit to match my real-time source ([\w-]).  I wasnt testing against the sample data (yes, I know this is all you had to work with)...either way, works in both C# and VB

Comment: can I ask a followup? I know how to alter the expression to grab any extra info before the condition line...but what If I'd like to grab the entire chunk of job info with matched conditions to output to a different file as well?

Comment: To get the entire job record, you can add an extra assertion group to the end like `(?ms)^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*(\w*)[\s-]*\*/(?:(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*\w*[\s-]*\*/).)*?\(v\([ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*\))+(?:(?!^[ \t]*/\*[\s-]*\w*[\s-]*\*/).)*`. Everything else is the same. The complete job record is in Groups[0].Value. Is that what you mean?.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(?<=/\*\s*-+\s(?<jobname>\w+)\s*-+\s*\*/(?:(?!/\*\s*-+).)*)\(v\((?<var>[^()]*)\)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%2F%5C*%5Cs*-%2B%5Cs(%3F%3Cjobname%3E%5Cw%2B)%5Cs*-%2B%5Cs*%5C*%2F(%3F%3A(%3F!%2F%5C*%5Cs*-%2B).)*)%5C(v%5C((%3F%3Cvar%3E%5B%5E()%5D*)%5C)&i=%2F*%20-----------------%20jobnameA%20-----------------%20*%2F%20%0D%0A%0D%0Ainsert_job%3A%20jobnameA%20%20%20job_type%3A%20CMD%20%0D%0Adate_conditions%3A%200%0D%0Aalarm_if_fail%3A%201%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%20-----------------%20jobnameB%20-----------------%20*%2F%20%0D%0A%0D%0Ainsert_job%3A%20jobnameB%20%20%20job_type%3A%20CMD%20%0D%0Adate_conditions%3A%201%0D%0Adays_of_week%3A%20tu%2Cwe%2Cth%2Cfr%2Csa%0D%0Acondition%3A%20s(job1)%20%26%20s(job2)%20%26%20(v(variable1)%20%3D%20%22Y%22%20%7C%20s(job1))%20%26%20(v(variable2)%20%3D%20%22Y%22%20%0D%0Aalarm_if_fail%3A%201%0D%0Ajob_load%3A%201%0D%0Apriority%3A%2010%0D%0A&o=s). **Note** that you need to use the regex with the `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier so that `.` could also match a newline.

The regex contains a positive lookbehind (that is infinite width in .NET) and inside it, there is a named capturing group `(?<jobname>\w+)` that captures the job name. It matches any characters up to the next `/* --- job --- */` for the global variables and captures them into Group "var" with `(?<var>[^()]*)`.

[image]

**Regex explanation:**

- `(?<=/\*\s*-+\s(?<jobname>\w+)\s*-+\s*\*/(?:(?!/\*\s*-+).)*)` - a positive lookahead that does not consume characters (just the pattern is checked for a match to return either true or false, if the engine should go on searching for the subsequent subpatterns or not) that expects to find before the next consuming subpattern:

  - `/\*\s*-+\s(?<jobname>\w+)\s*-+\s*\*/` - `/*` followed with 0+ space(s) followed with 1+ hyphens followed with a whitespace, then 1 or more word characters (captured into *jobname* capture group), and then again a space(s), hyphens and `*/`
  - `(?:(?!/\*\s*-+).)*` - a **[tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)** that matches anything but (or anything up to) `/*` + space(s) + hyphens.
- `\(v\((?<var>[^()]*)\)` - the global variable:

  - `\(v\(` - literal sequence `(v(`
  - `(?<var>[^()]*)` - Group *var* matching zero or more characters other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - literal `)`

Comment: Awesome!  Also thanks for indirectly pointing me to regexstorm...all the online testers I was using kept telling me that lookbehinds had to be zero-width (and had no .NET option).  I'll try this out now.

Comment: Also, check the [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) site for testing .NET regexes.

Comment: I had to swap [A-Z0-9\-] for \w for the jobname to allow for numbers and hyphenation, but it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: `\w` matches digits, too. To also match a hyphen, add it to the character class: `[\w-]`